# Regular Expression for preg_match

Tags: php, regex

I got following String:

```
ElFTkSuQmCC" alt="" width="auto" height="auto" /></td>
<td style="padding: 10px;">XX,X%</t
```

And want to have the "XX,X", so i build following regular expression:

`/QmCC" alt="" width="auto" height="auto" \/><\/td>\n<td style="padding: 10px;">(.*?)%/`

I tested it online and got a match for the XX,X but when i try to execute it in php with following code 
`preg_match_all('/REGEX/',$string,$match);`

It didn't match. Do you have any suggestions? The String is definitely in there. `var_dump($match)` gives me an empty array.

Thank you!

Comment: You should use a parser. Regex with HTML/XML will more than likely fail at some point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is in the newline. In your regex, there is `\n`. Use `\r\n` instead and it will work.

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Comment: Just a word of caution: that may work in this specific case, but it's better to just make your regexp be newline-unaware by using a modifier to let whitespace or the dot span over any possible newlines.

Answer (score 0):

Considering X as digit in your string:

```
$pattern = '/(\d{2},\d{1,2})/';

preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $match);
```

Comment: I should've said that the posted string is not the hole String i am really searching in.